# multiply str time ('0:00:00') to a float in Python

Tags: python

I try to multiply a series(column) of time string (ex: '0:00:00') to a series(column) of float numbers (ex: 1.1)

```
time_string = ['0:00:00', '0:00:00', '0:00:16', '0:00:09', '0:02:39', '0:07:19',
                 '0:02:00', '0:08:33', '0:08:30', '0:14:13', '0:07:24', '0:10:08']
float_num = [ 0.0,  1.1,  3.1, 10.1,  9.1,  5.1,  4.1,  2.1,  8.1,  6.1, 16.1, 17.1,]

time_string*float_num
```

I tried following:

```
time_string*float_num
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

```
time_string[0].dt.datetime.strptime("%H:%M:%S")*float_num[0]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

```
test = dt.datetime.strptime(time_string[0],"%H:%M:%S")
float(test) * float_num[0]
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

[Expecting result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA0Oi.png)

Please teach me how to get the correct result. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wording sounds a bit like you are using Pandas (series, column). If that's the case, you could try the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

time_string = [
    '0:00:00', '0:00:00', '0:00:16', '0:00:09', '0:02:39', '0:07:19',
    '0:02:00', '0:08:33', '0:08:30', '0:14:13', '0:07:24', '0:10:08'
]
float_num = [ 0.0,  1.1,  3.1, 10.1,  9.1,  5.1,  4.1,  2.1,  8.1,  6.1, 16.1, 17.1,]
df = pd.DataFrame({"time_string": time_string, "float_num": float_num})

time_deltas = pd.to_timedelta(df["time_string"]) * df["float_num"]
df["expect1"] = time_deltas.dt.total_seconds() / 86_400
df["expect2"] = (pd.Timestamp("2023") + time_deltas).dt.round("S").dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

First make timedeltas out of the `time_string` column via `pd.to_timedelta` and then multiply it by the column `float_num`. Afterwards take the resp. totals seconds and normalize them by the number of seconds of a day to get `expect1`. And finally use an arbitrary day to make an actual datetime out of the timedeltas to use `.dt.strftime` to get the `expect2` strings (there's a `.dt.round` in-between to the get the rounding you are expecting).

Result:

```
   time_string  float_num   expect1   expect2
0      0:00:00        0.0  0.000000  00:00:00
1      0:00:00        1.1  0.000000  00:00:00
2      0:00:16        3.1  0.000574  00:00:50
3      0:00:09       10.1  0.001052  00:01:31
4      0:02:39        9.1  0.016747  00:24:07
5      0:07:19        5.1  0.025913  00:37:19
6      0:02:00        4.1  0.005694  00:08:12
7      0:08:33        2.1  0.012469  00:17:57
8      0:08:30        8.1  0.047813  01:08:51
9      0:14:13        6.1  0.060223  01:26:43
10     0:07:24       16.1  0.082736  01:59:08
11     0:10:08       17.1  0.120333  02:53:17
```

Comment: this method works on my original dataset. I learn a lot more on pandas. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need to convert to a time object.  Each time value can be turned into a number of seconds by splitting the strings and multiplying the 3 components by their value in seconds.

The multiplication of these seconds by your float factors can then be turned into fractions of a day (dividing by 86400) or time representation (using a format string).

```
seconds  = [ h*3600+m*60+s for ts in time_string 
                           for h,m,s in [map(int,ts.split(":"))] ]
products = [ s*f for s,f in zip(seconds,float_num) ]

floatProduct = [ p/86400 for p in products ]
timeProduct  = [ "{}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(p//3600,p//60%60,p%60) 
                 for p in map(round,products) ]
```

output:

```
for ts,fn,fp,tp in zip(time_string,float_num,floatProduct,timeProduct):
    print(ts,f"{fn:4.1f}",f"{fp:9.7f}",tp,sep=" | ")

0:00:00 |  0.0 | 0.0000000 | 0:00:00
0:00:00 |  1.1 | 0.0000000 | 0:00:00
0:00:16 |  3.1 | 0.0005741 | 0:00:50
0:00:09 | 10.1 | 0.0010521 | 0:01:31
0:02:39 |  9.1 | 0.0167465 | 0:24:07
0:07:19 |  5.1 | 0.0259132 | 0:37:19
0:02:00 |  4.1 | 0.0056944 | 0:08:12
0:08:33 |  2.1 | 0.0124687 | 0:17:57
0:08:30 |  8.1 | 0.0478125 | 1:08:51
0:14:13 |  6.1 | 0.0602234 | 1:26:43
0:07:24 | 16.1 | 0.0827361 | 1:59:08
0:10:08 | 17.1 | 0.1203333 | 2:53:17
```

Comment: it shows error on first sentence of code:`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: It works with the `time_string` and `float_num` variables supplied in your question.  Perhaps you're trying it with a different `time_string` content that contain integers instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert your time to seconds then do your multiplication before converting them back to stings. You could do so with lambda functions as shown below.

The basic concept for sting to seconds is to split your string, convert the values to integers then multiply them by their base 60 position. The sum of this list will give you the seconds which you can multiply by your float.

For converting back to a string you can use integer division and modulo to return H:M:S and format them using an s string with zero padded digits.

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np

time_string = ['0:00:00', '0:00:00', '0:00:16', '0:00:09', '0:02:39', '0:07:19', '0:02:00', '0:08:33', '0:08:30', '0:14:13', '0:07:24', '0:10:08']
float_num = [ 0.0,  1.1,  3.1, 10.1,  9.1,  5.1,  4.1,  2.1,  8.1,  6.1, 16.1, 17.1,]

ts_to_seconds = lambda time_string, mult: (np.array(time_string.split(':')).astype(int)*[60**2, 60, 1]).sum() * mult
seconds_to_ts = lambda sec: '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (sec // (60**2), (sec % (60**2)) // 60, sec % 60)

output = []

for x, y in zip(time_string, float_num):
  output.append(ts_to_seconds(x, y))

print(output)
print([seconds_to_ts(round(x)) for x in output])
```

Comment: It shows error when I use it with my original dataset: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'`